# How to find a specific ID from an Array of Objects in Angular View

Tags: angular

I am building a shopping site and I want to switch a button Text from **'Add to cart'** to **'In Cart'**

**cart** array is set in **auth** provider so it's accessible in all components.

```
<button *ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn" (click)="addToCart()" class="button button-add-to-cart">
 <i class="fal fa-shopping-cart"></i>
  {{(auth.cart.length && (auth.cart[0].product._id == product.list[0]._id)) ? 'In Cart' : 'Add to Cart'}}
</button>
```

If I use above code then i can compare a product with the first element of the cart array wheather its in the cart or not, and it's working fine (when a product is in cart its showing In Cart).

But the problem is Cart has multiple item.

When I add multiple item it will not work. I have used **find** method Like this

```
{{(auth.cart.length && (auth.cart.find(x => x.product._id == product.list[0]._id) == product.list[0]._id)) ? 'In Cart' : 'Add to Cart'}}
```

But it's showing below error

```
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 41 in [ {{(auth.cart.length && (auth.cart.find(x => x.product._id == product.list[0]._id) == product.list[0]._id)) ? 'In Cart' : 'Add to Cart'}} ]
```

So Can I find that specific id from cart array ?

I need it from Angular View(html) not from .ts file

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Just wondering: why in html and not in ts? It's really a bad practice to run such logic in the view.

Comment: I'm a beginner in angular. Thought It will help me to do faster if I use it in view instead of ts file. Thanks for correcting me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `what-ever() => {..}` in .html. (this is the error that Angular shows)

You have two approaches:

1. Use a function in .ts

```
    getInCart(productId:any) => {
        return this.auth.cart && this.auth.cart.find(x=>x.product._id==productId)
          ? 'in cart' : 'add to cart'
    }
```

And in your .html

```html
    {{ getInCart(product._id) }}
```

2. In your `this.auth.cart` array items, add a new property "inCart" and manually set this property to `true` whenever the user adds the item to cart and to `false` when the user removes it.

The first approach has the advantage of minimal changes. The "cost" is **less performance** (remember that when you put a function in .html this is executed for each detection cycle - if you have a mousemove this can be critical).

NOTE: Another approach is using a template reference variable, use `ViewChildren` and ask about the `nativeElement` with a certain attribute - but I imagine that this is not what are you looking for.

```html
<div #element [id]="'product' + i">
```

```
@ViewChildren('element') elements: QueryList<ElementRef>

findElement(productId) {
    const element = this.elements.find(x=> 
        x.nativeElement.getAttribute('id') == productId)
    // element only gives you the ElementRef
    // without reference to your array
    return element;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir/Ma'am @eliseo for your valueable time and help. It's working really fine. I'm using Approach 1.